# concatenating the two variable output into one line python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two variables holding the ouputs from using `subprocess` output and want the output of the both variable to be printed into one line..
below is the details..

```
cmd1=subprocess.Popen("some_command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd_input1=cmd1.stdout.read().decode('utf8')

cmd_input1 has:

one
two
three
four


cmd2=subprocess.Popen("othere_command", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cmd_input2=cmd2.stdout.read().decode('utf8')

while cmd_input2 has :
1
2
3
4
```

I need the print output of both the variables into one line, line below..

```
one   1
two   2
three 3
four  4
```

I tried below but not working.. i just started learning python..

```
print("%  %." % (cmd_input1, cmd_input2)
```

Its python3 , please guide..

Comment: try.. `print(cmd_input1,  str(cmd_input2))`

Comment: not working,  still printing the output into one after another not into one line as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to use [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) built-in function to mix two lists and [split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) to split the output to lists of strings.

Zip will make a list of tuples:

```
[('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4)]
```

Then you'll need to print it out. Here's the full code:

```
zipped = zip(cmd_input1.split('\n'), cmd_input2.split('\n'))
for line in zipped:
    print(line[0], line[1])
```

Comment: ababak, thx for the great input, that works nice, but it looks like if there are missing value in the cmd_input2 then its taking the next number joining into the cmd_input, would be great to suggest on this

Comment: Well, zip will aggregate elements from each of the lists one by one and it will stop when any of the lists are over. I am not sure what do you mean when you say missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over both outputs simultaneously by splitting them into lines and [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ping them:

```
for out1, out2 in zip(cmd_input1.splitlines(), cmd_input2.splitlines()):
    print(out1.ljust(5), out2)
```

I also used [`str.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to align the output.

Comment: great ans indeed anx for the solution but it looks like if there are missing value in the cmd_input2 then its taking the next number joining into the cmd_input, would be great to suggest on this